# using classes and rendering api call in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I am totally new in React Native, I am having problem rendering data from API call. When I do it inside function it is working for me when I am using useEffect... but in the Class I cannot use that.

Here is example of my code...

```
export default class Categories extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            data: [],
            error: null,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.regionsGetRequest();
    }
    regionsGetRequest = () => {
        this.setState({ loading: true });

        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'https://...........json'
            );
            this.setState({
                data: result.data,
                error: result.error || null,
                loading: false,
            });

        };
        fetchData();
    };

    renderCategories = () => {
        const categoryLive = this.state.data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(categoryLive));
```

I am getting in console: undefined, undefined... and then results as they should... like it is running 3 times for some reason... if I try to put above renderCategories:

```
componentDidMount() {
        renderCategories();
    }
```

I am getting just one undefined... when I connect variable categoryLive nothing is loading.

Sorry I have been strugling with this one... any help is really appreciated!!

No matter what I do, I am always getting 3 calls... first two empty object [], and third I get real results dumped in console. So my categories are not rendering.. they are empty.

Here is updated code, and I am posting whole file, it might ring some bells.

```
export default class Categories extends React.Component {
    state = {
        myData: [],
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get('https://..............json')
            .then((res) => {
                const myData = res.data;
                this.setState({ myData });
            });
    }

    renderCategories = () => {
        const categoryLive = this.state.myData;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(categoryLive));

        const { navigation, route } = this.props;
        const tabId = route.params?.tabId;
        const categories = tabId
            ? categoryLive[tabId]
            : categoryLive.victoria_bc;
        //console.log(route.params?.tabId);
        return (
            <ScrollView
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.categoryList}
            >
                <Block flex>
                    {categories.map((category) => (
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                            key={`category-${category.id}`}
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Category', { ...category })}
                        >
                            <Block flex card style={[styles.category, styles.shadow]}>
                                <ImageBackground
                                    source={{ uri: category.image }}
                                    style={[
                                        styles.imageBlock,
                                        { width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2, height: 252 },
                                    ]}
                                    imageStyle={{
                                        width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2,
                                        height: 252,
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Block style={styles.categoryTitle}>
                                        <Text size={18} bold color={theme.COLORS.WHITE}>
                                            {category.title}
                                        </Text>
                                    </Block>
                                </ImageBackground>
                            </Block>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    ))}
                </Block>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Block flex center style={styles.categories}>
                {this.renderCategories()}
            </Block>
        );
    }
}
```

When I put it like this: I am getting default category ( and all data just fine... ) but my navigation is not working any more... (route.params?.tabId is not updating)

```
axios
    .get('https://.............json')
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            myData: res.data,
                error: res.error || null,
                loading: false,
            });
            console.log('inside .then----' + JSON.stringify(this.state.myData));
            const { navigation, route } = this.props;
            const tabId = route.params?.tabId;
            const tmpCategories = tabId
                ? this.state.myData[tabId]
                : this.state.myData.victoria_bc;
            this.setState({ categories: tmpCategories });
            //console.log(route.params?.tabId);
        });
```

If I put it like this as below... category is empty for me:

```
axios
    .get('https://.............json')
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            myData: res.data,
                error: res.error || null,
                loading: false,
            });
            console.log('inside .then----' + JSON.stringify(this.state.myData));

        });
        const { navigation, route } = this.props;
        const tabId = route.params?.tabId;
        const tmpCategories = tabId
            ? this.state.myData[tabId]
            : this.state.myData.victoria_bc;
        this.setState({ categories: tmpCategories });
        //console.log(route.params?.tabId);
```

Final code that is working for me..

```
export default class Categories extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            myData: [],
            error: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.renderCategories();
    }

    renderCategories = () => {
        axios
            .get('https://.............json')
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    myData: res.data,
                    error: res.error || null,
                    loading: false,
                });
                //console.log('inside .then----' + JSON.stringify(this.state.myData));
            });
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <View
                    style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
                >
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            );
        } else {
            const { navigation, route } = this.props;
            const tabId = route.params?.tabId;
            const categories = tabId
                ? this.state.myData[tabId]
                : this.state.myData.victoria_bc;

            //console.log(route.params?.tabId);


            return (
                <Block flex center style={styles.categories}>
                    <ScrollView
                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                        contentContainerStyle={styles.categoryList}
                    >
                        <Block flex>
                            {categories.map((category) => (
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                                    key={`category-${category.id}`}
                                    onPress={() =>
                                        navigation.navigate('Category', { ...category })
                                    }
                                >
                                    <Block flex card style={[styles.category, styles.shadow]}>
                                        <ImageBackground
                                            source={{ uri: category.image }}
                                            style={[
                                                styles.imageBlock,
                                                { width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2, height: 252 },
                                            ]}
                                            imageStyle={{
                                                width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2,
                                                height: 252,
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Block style={styles.categoryTitle}>
                                                <Text size={18} bold color={theme.COLORS.WHITE}>
                                                    {category.title}
                                                </Text>
                                            </Block>
                                        </ImageBackground>
                                    </Block>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            ))}
                        </Block>
                    </ScrollView>
                </Block>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default class Categories extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      myData: [],
      error: null,
      categories: []
    };


  }

    componentDidMount() {
    renderCategories();
    }

    renderCategories = () => {
        this.setState({ loading: true });

         axios
        .get('https://..............json')
        .then((res) => {

            this.setState({ myData: res.data,
                            error: res.error || null,
                            loading: false 
            });
            const categoryLive = this.state.myData;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(categoryLive));
        });



    };

    render() {
       // Set params in your render method :


        const { navigation, route } = this.props;
        const tabId = route.params?.tabId;

        if (this.state.loading){
            return (
            <View style={{ flex : 1, alignItems:  'center', justifyContent:  'center' }}>
                <ActivityIndicator/>
                </View>

                );
            }   
        return (

  // assign in your return statement  
     this.setState({ categories: tabId
            ? categoryLive[tabId]
            : categoryLive.victoria_bc;})

        //console.log(route.params?.tabId);
            const { categories } = this.state.categories;
         <Block flex center style={styles.categories}>
            <ScrollView
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.categoryList}
            >
                <Block flex>
                    {categories.map((category) => (
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                            key={`category-${category.id}`}
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Category', { ...category })}
                        >
                            <Block flex card style={[styles.category, styles.shadow]}>
                                <ImageBackground
                                    source={{ uri: category.image }}
                                    style={[
                                        styles.imageBlock,
                                        { width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2, height: 252 },
                                    ]}
                                    imageStyle={{
                                        width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2,
                                        height: 252,
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Block style={styles.categoryTitle}>
                                        <Text size={18} bold color={theme.COLORS.WHITE}>
                                            {category.title}
                                        </Text>
                                    </Block>
                                </ImageBackground>
                            </Block>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    ))}
                </Block>
            </ScrollView>
        </Block>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replay,  //Please make sure it is https! - yes, it is https, 2. //Here your data is res.results as json, you can log it or process it.. I am setting state 'state.data' but when I refer it in renderCategories function below I am always geting [] [] and then in as 3-rd call I get results.

Comment: I updated code to make it more simple.. always getting result only in 3-rd refresh. I put whole code in the question it might be easier to read. Thanks for help!

Comment: Almost, almost there... I totally understand concept now... It is totally rendering as expected, but when route.params?.tabId is changing nothing happens. it looks like I have to trigger renderCategories whenever I change category maybe... not sure. I posted two pieces of code, one is rendering data (but only for default category), other one just like you advised and that is more logical to me is returning empty category. Have a look please at the updated question. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: assign props for navigation in your render method so add this code to like render(){ const { navigation, route } = this.props;
        const tabId = route.params?.tabId; .........} and then do the if statement in your  with assigning the state return  method so return( const tabId = route.params?.tabId;
        const tmpCategories = tabId
            ? this.state.myData[tabId]
            : this.state.myData.victoria_bc;
        this.setState({ categories: tmpCategories });
        //console.log(route.params?.tabId);   .............)

Comment: So basically every time you render you reassign and give the route params thus tabId the value you need. 

If you found this answer useful, make sure to accept it (:

Comment: Thanks a lot... I seams to be working... what I did I set initial loading to true... and moved constants set after if (this.state.loading) ... so I made sure that I have data. This was really educational. I'll add my whole code in my original question.. in case anybody need it.